# pillow jpeg file size

Tags: python, jpeg, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to write a Python script that loads a jpeg file, rotates the image by 90 degrees, and then saves the result at about the same level of compression as the original.  I've looked at the documentation at https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/ImageFile.html, but don't see any way to control the size/quality of the output file.

Comment: The [tutorial](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/handbook/tutorial.html) shows some examples where the image is resized, as well as output to postscript at 75 dpi.

Comment: The hard part will be figuring out what compression the original file used, that's not a standard (it varies by application) and it's not recorded in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the incoming quality? Which functions are you using? I just jumped over to the docs and the save function takes a named parameter "quality".

http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/handbook/image-file-formats.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for lossless rotation, you should not use Pillow. There is [jpegtran](http://jpegclub.org/jpegtran/) program. It is part of libjpeg and `libjpeg-progs` package in Ubuntu.